# Maskable interrupts and non-maskable in 8086

Tags: microprocessor

I have a question about interrupts at 8086, is the fact that a non-maskable interrupt can be invalidated by Reset and not by user, a correct one?

Comment: In the sense that reset overrides anything else going on, yes.

Comment: Once you're in an NMI handler, the way out is by the IRET type of instruction. Another NMI can also interrupt one ongoing NMI. So, the NMI signal must be clean and not bounce.   And yes, hardware reset will make the processor forget everything, including that it was in an NMI ISR !  I dont understand "invalidating NMI by user" in the question . NMI cannot be masked by any instructions the user can run on the processor. Not sure thats what you meant.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop That's an answer I'd vote for.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much @kalyanswaroop